# Is there a website which is having the collection of all the lecture notes of Pure and Applied mathematics?

Tags: self-learning, online-resources, lecture-notes

Going to be doing a lot of self-studying this summer and found this really great resource for topics in theoretical physics by David Tong.

http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html

Does anyone know of a format similar to this but for topics in mathematics (specifically at the graduate level)?

Comment: There are a lot of Tex'd lecture notes:  I have compiled a short list in an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1560607/276134.   Otherwise, MIT OCW has a lot of material.

Answer (score 3):

[Pdf link](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/)collections of lecture notes   of Cambridge university Professor . Notes contains  both Pure and Apllied topics.

Check out this  [link](https://www.math.miami.edu/%7Edsolis/notes.html) contains both pure and applied topics

Also,check out this [link](https://realnotcomplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The internet is full of mathematical lecture notes from all around the world. MIT opensource has a lot of video courses with associated lecture notes, for example. But one source that came to my mind is [Cambridge Tripos III lecture notes page](https://www.archim.org.uk/lecturenotes/part_iii). Note that these lecture notes are aimed to advanced studends (specially graduate students).

Comment: Thanks very much